# Error while pushing the gem to rubygems.org (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've build a gem and try to push it to rubygems.org.

When executing `gem push gem_name-1.0.0.gem` I get this error after I've entered my credentials:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::ConfigFile::FileUtils
Dit you mean? FileTest
```

But I don't use FileUtils in my Ruby application. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: What gem version do you use (`gem env version`)?

Comment: @spickermann: - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `gem` seems to be affected by the issue described [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3976). The maintainer answered in the thread on GitHub that the bug was fixed in the meantime.

Therefore, I suggest updating your local version of `gem` with the following command:

```
gem update --system
```